# JS how to use two arithmetic operators

Tags: javascript, math

i want to get data from input fields and do  two arithmetic operations at same time  (1)multiplication (2) addition. Multiplication is working but when i try to do 2nd operation i get some error. for example 2*2+2=6 but when i try the answer comes 42.

my code is here .

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sfpm,#snom,#bonus').keyup(function(){
      var a =$('#sfpm').val();
      var b = $('#snom').val();
      var c = $("#bonus").val();
      var taamount = a*b+c ;
      $('#staamount').val(taamount);
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: `'2'*'2' + '2' => 4 + '2' => '42'`. Use numbers for arithmetic instead of strings and you'll get the answer you expect.

Comment: It's like a `police + dog = policedog`, your'e doing maths with strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript ... See also: parseInt(), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt and parseFloat(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: Use `parseInt(a, 10)` to convert your strings to numbers. You will need to check that the final result `!isNaN(taamount)`

Comment: `parseInt` ok if your only want integer arithmetic,.  `parseFloat`, or `Number(val)` would make sense.

Comment: @RyanWheale i checked your link but i still don't understand how to implement this code into my code ..can you write my code  in your formate for understanding? please..

Comment: `var a = parseInt($('#sfpm').val(), 10);`, `var b = parseInt($('#snom').val(), 10);`, `var c = parseInt($('#bonus').val(), 10);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this example the first box will cause multiplication, but the rest will *concatenate*  ( simply append to ) the last digit present, which increases length but doesn't do any mathematical operation.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
sfpm<input id="sfpm">
snom<input id="snom">
bonus<input id="bonus">
<hr/>total<input id="staamount">


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sfpm,#snom,#bonus').keyup(function(){
      var a =$('#sfpm').val();
      var b = $('#snom').val();
      var c = $("#bonus").val();
      var taamount = a*b+c ;
      $('#staamount').val(taamount);
    });
  });

</script>
```

This is because you're adding two strings together instead of numbers. Strings added together look like this:

```js
let str = "Hello ", str2= "world!";

console.log(str + str2);
```

So it makes sense that they *append*. Numbers look like this:

```js
console.log(1 + 5);
```

Which does what you expect, but the important thing to realize is that the *+* operator has multiple functions. it can either *append* or perform *math*. The difference as to what type of operation is performed is based solely on the `type` of the data you're using.

- a string will append
- a number will add

So in your code when you get the value using `.val()` - what's happening is that you're getting *string* values, not *number* values. To fix this we can do a few different things.

`parseInt` or `Number` methods will convert the values from `.val()` into integers:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
sfpm<input id="sfpm">
snom<input id="snom">
bonus<input id="bonus">
<hr/>total<input id="staamount">


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sfpm,#snom,#bonus').keyup(function(){
      var a = parseInt($('#sfpm').val());
      var b = Number($('#snom').val());
      var c = parseInt($("#bonus").val());
      var taamount = a*b+c ;
      $('#staamount').val(taamount || 0);
    });
  });

</script>
```

One *other* way to coerce a string to a number is to simply place the `+` operator before the value. This will cause the interpreter to automatically try to change the value into a number.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
sfpm<input id="sfpm"> snom
<input id="snom"> bonus
<input id="bonus">
<hr/>total<input id="staamount">


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sfpm,#snom,#bonus').keyup(function() {
      var a = +$('#sfpm').val();
      var b = +$('#snom').val();
      var c = +$("#bonus").val();
      var taamount = a * b + c;
      $('#staamount').val(taamount || 0);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt() to ensure you are getting the int version of the value, it looks like it is adding c as a string

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to operate on string.

You're doing something **'2'** + **'0'** which will result as **'20'** not **2**.

Because here + operator does the concatenation of two string not arithmetic addition

Change it number.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sfpm,#snom,#bonus').keyup(function(){
      var a =Number($('#sfpm').val());
      var b = Number($('#snom').val());
      var c = Number($("#bonus").val());
      var taamount = a*b+c ;
      $('#staamount').val(taamount);
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#afee,#bcost #ucost').keyup(function(){
      var a =Number($('#afee').val());
      var b = Number($('#bcost').val());
      var c = Number($("#ucost").val());
      var taamount = a+b+c ;
      $('#tcost').val(taamount);
    });
  });

</script>

Comment: can you share a codepen or jsfiddle link ? @AtifRaja